# Postgres standalone in Windows - command prompt not working as expected

Tags: windows, postgresql, cmd, terminal

I have a system where I do not have admin rights. I downloaded Postgres 12.4 standalone zip version and followed documentation about how to install it. An easier article here:

[Install PostgreSQL Without Admin Rights on Windows 10 OS](https://app.getpocket.com/read/3058556381)

When I start postgres from CMD terminal (using the command mentioned in the article), everything is fine; but one strange issue is there. The terminal window returns and wait for the next command when I enter the start command as expected.

But when I close the terminal window, Postgres DB also crashes along with it. I can understand if the command is not returning, but here the command returns and terminal waits for the next command and it executes any command you enter in terminal as expected.  Basically, I want to start Postgres in background and it should not crash when I close the terminal window. I even tried to prefix the command with "start ", but it just opens another window and that window just awaits till Postgres is shut down (if you close that window forcefully, Postgres crashes). I am bit confused and want to understand how this can be resolved (without installing it as a service).

I guess if I install it as a service, this problem may not happen. But I cannot do that as I do not have admin rights I think. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Start the server in one `cmd.exe` and `psql` in a second `cmd.exe`, then that won't happen.

Comment: Laurenz, I rarely use psql. I just want to close the terminal after postgres server start. I connect using my java program or postgres admin.

Comment: Oh, I see. Probably that is not easily possible on Windows.

Comment: MySQL has that. Even if you use the standalone version of MySQL, MySQL daemon (mysqld.exe) will continue to run in the background if you close CMD. Not sure if postgres has a similar feature